ZTE Router requires Internet reset to reconnect to Internet (No Internet, Secure) (LAN/WiFi)
I’ll try to be as specific as possible with the little network knowledge I possess, I’m sorry in advance if I butcher something, english is not my first language.
One day my household lost internet connection, so after various internet resets (both through IPS and manual router reset) and checking that there were no incidents or work in my area, the IPS decided to send a technician to check the issue. When he arrived he said they gave him instructions to upgrade our current cables for optic fiber and replace and upgrade all IPS related devices such as modem, router, repeater and TV decoder. After all of that, he gave us our new WiFi network and password. Everything connected properly until the next morning.
Since then every time I turn on my PC or work laptop I am connected with no internet and the only way to fix it is reseting the router.
My new router is a ZTE Wifi6 model.
Symptoms:

On my PC (LAN)

Troubleshooter reports Ethernet doesn’t have a valid IP configuration.


On my laptop (Wifi)

The connection shows “no internet, secured”.
The troubleshooter reports “Could not find DHCP adapter”.


It’s not like all devices disconnect at the same time, it’s about our devices recognizing the connection, since someone else can be connected properly and it could give me trouble at the same time when I turn on my PC.

What I’ve tried:

Verified the physical cables and connections, made sure everything is properly connected.
After two more failed visits from IPS, they changed my router to a new one.
Verified that DHCP is enabled on the router configuration.
Checked there’s enough range of available IPs for all devices.
Verified the lease time.
Tried assigning static IPs to my PC and laptop.
Checked for firmware updates with my IPS, since I cannot access ZTE’s firmwares as a user. (They say it’s up to date).

Router details

Model: ZTE ZXHN F6640P
Firmware version: V3.0.10P6N3B
Lease time: 86400s

What can I do to fix this? Should I keep contacting my IPS tech support or is it not worth it
